# C: Finding Huffman-coded path of specific leaf in tree

Tags: c, recursion, tree, traversal, huffman-code

I'm trying to write a recursive function that locates a specific leaf within a Huffman tree, then prints its shortest path with zeros and ones (zero being a traversal to the left, and one being a traversal to the right).  I understand the logic of what I need to do, but I'm not having success at actually implementing it.  I believe that I have a good skeleton here, but the part I'm missing is some more complicated logic to tell when I should actually run printf and when I should not (since this currently just prints every zero and one).  Also, I know that the rest of the logic outside of this is working properly because if you do a normal traversal where you do not have to plot the shortest paths, each of the elements I am searching for is found.

I've tried looking at quite a few resources online and I cannot find a solution, or at least, I cannot recognize the solution properly.  I've probably rewritten this 50 or more times.  Let me know what you think!

```
void traverse(struct tree *curr, struct tree *cmp)
{
  if (curr == NULL)
  {
    return;
  }

  if (getLeft(curr) == NULL && getRight(curr) == NULL)
  {
    if (curr == cmp)
    {
      return;
    }
  }

  if (getLeft(curr) != NULL)
  {
    printf("0");

    traverse(getLeft(curr), cmp);
  }

  if (getRight(curr) != NULL)
  {
    printf("1");

    traverse(getRight(curr), cmp);
  }
}
```

For context: `cmp` is the node we want to find, `getLeft()` and `getRight()` return the left and right children of a node respectively, and `curr` starts as the root of the Huffman tree itself.  Also, the reason this printf thing works is because I loop through all of the known leaves, print other information about the leaf, and then call this traversal method, followed by a newline.

Answer (score 3):

There are several solutions.

First, you could traverse the entire tree as you are doing and build a table of codes. Then use the table, not the tree. Then you're not wasting your time searching the whole tree for every code. As you traverse the tree you build up a string of 0's and 1's, and when you get to a leaf, you save the built up string and the symbol in the leaf in the table. Then throw away the tree. This is the recommended approach.

Second, your links could be bidirectional. Since you have a pointer to the leaf, you could simply start at the leaf and work your way back to the root, constructing the string of 0's and 1's in reverse.

Third, you could persist in doing your painful tree search for every leaf by having your traverse function return true or false. It would return true if either it got to the desired leaf, or if one of the traverse calls returned true. Then depending on which traverse call returned true, you would print or save a zero or a one. This would print the path in reverse. If you save them in a string in reverse order instead of printing, then you can print the string when the first traverse call returns.

Answer (score 1):

A viable solution is to give each node a `parent` pointer. This way, once you find the leaf, you can traverse up the tree recursively starting at that leaf, and print the appropriate bits as you return from the recursive calls.

In this function, first check if the node has a parent or not (in other words, if we're at the root or not), and if so, call the function recursively with the node's parent; if not, return.

In the case that we called the function recursively, after the recursive call, check to see if the current node is the right child of its parent. If so, print a 1; if not, print a 0.

No need to worry about reversing a string in this implementation.

Another possible solution would be to build up the string and pass it along to the recursive calls. For this solution, you'd need to know the height of the tree, or at least the number of symbols your tree can encode so that you pass in a char array of at least that size, plus one for null termination.

In pseudocode, this would look like:

```
func traverse (cur, cmp, str)
    if cur == null, return
    if cur == cmp
        print str
    if cur.left != null
        traverse(cur.left, cmp, str + "0")
    if cur.right != null
        traverse(cur.right, cmp, str + "1")
```

This way, you're building up the string, and only print it once you find the leaf in question. Note that I moved the `cur == cmp` check outside of that if statement, because it should never be true for an internal node in a Huffman code tree. This method is wildly inefficient for finding the code for one character, though, since it performs a DFS on the entire tree.

Comment: Your first approach effectively builds the string information in reverse on the stack and reverses it when returning from the recursive calls. Instead of recursion, you  can just have a loop that saves the string in memory, taking a lot less space than a recursive call on the stack for every character. If you know the maximum depth of the tree, you can just store the characters in reverse, so that you don't actually have to do any reversing at the end.

Comment: Your second approach is how one would build a table, by saving the result at every leaf instead of printing it at just one of the leaves.

Comment: @MarkAdler this recursive formulation and a loop formulation observe the same time complexity (barring function call overhead), which is linear in the maximum depth of the tree (the number of characters encoded by the tree). The space complexity for the recursive is also linear in the maximum depth, so it's virtually negligible for any modern machine.

Comment: @MarkAdler for the second, you're right, I can add in that the method is an implementation of what you said. I can also mention that the table method can get you constant-time coding amortized if you store them in a hashtable.

Comment: I'm one of those odd people that care about the constant in front of the _n_ for an O(_n_) process.